# log4net file rolling for multiple log files - File Name

Tags: log4net

Generally log4net creates rolling files as follows when the file reaches the given size limit.

```
log.txt
log.txt.1
log.txt.2
```

Is it possible to create the rolling files as below.

```
log.txt
log1.txt
log2.txt
```

The reason I am looking for the above functionality is because I am reading all the .txt files and generating a report. When the file name has extension as .1, it is not recognized as .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the relevant log4net\appender section of your `.config` file:

```
<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
```

This should give you the following file names:

```
log.txt
log.1.txt
log.2.txt
```